# How to add 2 additional variables in window.checkoutConfig on Magento 2 Checkout page

Tags: magento2, magento2.4

I want to send 2 arrays from different models to the checkout page via CompositeConfigProvider. But it seems that it only works for one model. I'm not sure if I misconfigured the frontend/di.xml file.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow below steps

**app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/frontend/di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <!-- pass custom variable to checkout page -->
    <type name="Magento\Checkout\Model\CompositeConfigProvider">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="configProviders" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="city_provider" xsi:type="object">Vendor\Module\Model\Cities</item>
                <item name="sub_ditrict_provider" xsi:type="object">Vendor\Module\Model\SubDistricts</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
</config>
```

Create a file **app/code/Vendor/Module/Model/Cities.php**

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Model;

use Magento\Checkout\Model\ConfigProviderInterface;

class Cities implements ConfigProviderInterface
{
    public function getConfig()
    {
        $config = [];
        $config['city_provider'] = 'city_name_here';

        return $config;
    }
}
```

Create another file **app/code/Vendor/Module/Model/SubDistricts.php**

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Model;

use Magento\Checkout\Model\ConfigProviderInterface;

class SubDistricts implements ConfigProviderInterface
{
    public function getConfig()
    {
        $config = [];
        $config['sub_district_provider'] = 'sub_district_name_here';

        return $config;
    }
}
```

Inside your checkout js file,
You can get value using below format,

```
var cityName = window.checkoutConfig.city_provider;
var subDistrictName = window.checkoutConfig.sub_district_provider;

console.log('City '. cityName);
console.log('Sub District Name '. subDistrictName);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the example,

**di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Checkout\Model\CompositeConfigProvider">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="providers" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="provider1" xsi:type="object">Vendor\Module\Model\Provider1</item>
                <item name="provider2" xsi:type="object">Vendor\Module\Model\Provider2</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
</config>
```

**provider1**

```
namespace Vendor\Module\Model;

use Magento\Checkout\Model\ConfigProviderInterface;

class Provider1 implements ConfigProviderInterface
{
    public function getConfig()
    {
        return [
            'provider1_data' => ['value1', 'value2', 'value3'],
        ];
    }
}
```

**Provider2**

```
namespace Vendor\Module\Model;

use Magento\Checkout\Model\ConfigProviderInterface;

class Provider2 implements ConfigProviderInterface
{
    public function getConfig()
    {
        return [
            'provider2_data' => ['foo', 'bar', 'baz'],
        ];
    }
}
```